# Let $a$ be a $p$-cycle in $S_p$, and let $b$ be a transposition in $S_p$. Show $S_p$ is generated by $a$ and $b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, symmetric-groups

I want to solve the following:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a$ be a $p$-cycle in $S_p$, and let $b$ be a transposition in $S_p$. Show $S_p$ is generated by $a$ and $b$.

**My attempt**

Write $a=(y_1 \space y_2 \space ...\space y_p)$ and $b=(z_1 \space z_2)$. WLOG, $y_1=z_1=1$. WLOG, we can also assume $a=(1 \space 2 \space ... \space p).$

Let $σ\in S_p$. It should be obvious that $σ$ is a product of transpositions, so to show $σ \in S_p$, it suffices to show every transposition can be written in terms of $(1 \space 2 \space ... \space p)$ and $(1 \space z_2)$. But how do I show this?

**Duplicate? I think not.**

Although another question (already answered on math.SE) is similar to mine, I do not believe that mine is a duplicate. The other question is equivalent to mine only for the special case when $z_2=2$, but not for general $z_2$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use in a simpler typographic matter the fact that $p$ is a prime, let us use the symbols $0,1,2,\dots(p-1)$ to be permuted. We have to show that the cycle $c$ and a transposition 
$$
\begin{aligned}
c &= (0,1,2\dots,(p-1))\ ,\\
t &= (0,a)\ ,\ a\ne 0\ ,\ a\in \Bbb F_p\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
are generating the full permutation group. Let $G$ be the group generated by $c,t$.

We conjugate $t$ with $c$, so all transpositions $(k, k+a)$ are in $G$.

So $(0,a)$, $(a,2a)$, $(2a,3a)$, $\dots$ are in $G$.

We stop the above at the $b$-value, ($b$ is both seen in $\Bbb Z$ and in $\Bbb F_p$, depending on context,) so that $ab=1$ in $\Bbb F_p$.

Now, using
$$(0,a), \ (a,2a), \ (2a,3a),\ \dots\ ((b-1)a,1)$$
we can produce iteratively 
$$(0,a), \ (0,2a),\ (0,3a),\ \dots\ (0,\underbrace{1}_{ba})\ .$$
(For instance, $(0,a)(a,2a)(0,a)=(0,2a)$.)
Finally, $c$ and $(0,1)$ are standard generators for the full symmetric group.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: how's that you can write $t$ and $c$ both starting at $0$?
What you're doing when you re-write $c$ is basically to stabish a permutation on $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$, but given a random transposition $(i,j)$ how can you garantee that the same permutation sends $i$ to $0$?

Comment: @SamHaze $c$ and $t$ are permutations of a set of symbols, which we may assume are not numbers first, we intentionally want to avoid integers at this step. Then pick a symbol among the two symbols in the transposition. Now write the $p$-cycle to start with the same symbol as a cycle, and use a new notation using integers $0,1,2,\dots$ instead of the symbols, replacing the symbols in order so that the cycle becomes $(0,1,2,3,\dots,(p-1))$